# LinkedIn Lead Gen to Pardot List?

Tags: visual-workflow, pardot, linkedin

I'm trying to think how I can automate this when I have 60+ campaigns going on.

Essentially I'm looking at the cleanest way to add a Lead to a CRM campaign and a Pardot List based on LinkedIn Lead Gen hidden fields.

Is the general rule to capture the campaign and list from a hidden lead gen field, then  make a Flow to assign them to a CRM campaign and maybe capture the list in a field too so when they sync with Pardot I can use an automation rule?

Thanks!

Comment: That's at least how we handled it as well. We do additional parsing on the general lead source, but otherwise I don't see a way how we find additional campaign information on just the standard LinkedIn lead fields

Comment: @Hyperzwerg It seems though, in Pardot, I can't grab the hidden Lead field as a variable to use in a completion action or automation rule. It only allows me to select from a static list of campaigns and list (rather than the value from from a field on Prospect / Lead). Any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

If the "LinkedIn Lead" is first hitting Salesforce as a "Lead", having a Salesforce Flow to add them to SF Campaign is great.

Depending how fancy you want to get, you could go a bit crazy and do something like this (which leverages [Flow Actions for Pardot](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000Qt7uzEAB), though you could use other means of calling the Pardot API):

- Check the SF Campaign record to see if a (custom) field "Pardot_List_Id__c" has a value.
- If it doesn't, use the Create A Static List action (from the package) to create your static list
- Upsert the Prospect (from the package), to make sure the Prospect exists in Pardot (might jump the sync a bit early, also lets you set the Pardot Campaign ID if you want to use something other than the connector setting Campaign)
- Add the Prospect to the Static List
- Update the Campaign if you had to create a NEW static list during this run.